# Error calling t-sql function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, split

I have a table valued function shown here:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitStr]
   (@sep char(1), @s nvarchar(512))
RETURNS table
AS
    RETURN (
    WITH Pieces(pn, start, stop) AS (
        SELECT 1, 1, CHARINDEX( @sep, @s )
        UNION ALL
        SELECT pn + 1, stop + 1, CHARINDEX( @sep, @s, stop + 1 )
        FROM Pieces
        WHERE stop > 0
    )
    SELECT
        pn,
        SUBSTRING( @s, start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop-start ELSE 512 END ) AS s
    FROM
        Pieces
)
```

I now try to call it from another script like this:

```
declare @referencestring varchar(512)
declare @s varchar(512)

set @s = 'cow is running|-reference_temp|horse is jumping';

set @referencestring = (select ss.val 
                        from (select dbo.SplitStr(@s, '|') as val) ss 
                        where ss.val like '%-reference%');
```

But doing that gives me error:

> Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.SplitStr", or the name is ambiguous.

All I want to do is that the table that gets returned from the split function has three rows, I just want the row that contains the string `-reference` in it as a string. It should get stored in the `referencestring` variable.

Comment: try executing select dbo.SplitStr(@s, '|')  alone. shouldn't that be a select * from  dbo.SplitStr(@s, '|') ?

Comment: Your function returns a table. You need to say `SELECT <cols> FROM dbo.function(...);`, not `SELECT dbo.function(...);`. Anyway, this is not the most efficient way to split strings - please see http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings and, more importantly, http://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-now-with-less-t-sql

Comment: @Aaron - Thanks, but what should I write in place of <cols> ?

Comment: @shawnt00 - No the database is correct and function does exists.

Comment: @schudel - Yes select * from dbo.SplitStr('some string', '|') gives an output but the output is wrong. It just contains one row and two columns --> 1, |

Comment: @vvv I assume your SplitStr function is not correct. I second Aaron. You should try and use one of his links to get a correct split function

Comment: Thanks. Actually I got the right output now. the first parameter is the separator and not the string. I was calling it incorrectly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on Aarons links, this works:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings_Moden
(
   @List NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN
  WITH E1(N)        AS ( SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 
                         UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 
                         UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1),
       E2(N)        AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b),
       E4(N)        AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b),
       E42(N)       AS (SELECT 1 FROM E4 a, E2 b),
       cteTally(N)  AS (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT TOP (DATALENGTH(ISNULL(@List,1))) 
                         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E42),
       cteStart(N1) AS (SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t
                         WHERE (SUBSTRING(@List,t.N,1) = @Delimiter OR t.N = 0))
  SELECT Item = SUBSTRING(@List, s.N1, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@List,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000))
    FROM cteStart s;

go


declare @referencestring varchar(512)
declare @s varchar(512)

set @s = 'cow is running|-reference_temp|horse is jumping';

set @referencestring = (select item from dbo.SplitStrings_Moden(@s, '|') 
                        where item like '%-reference%');

print @referencestring
```

Comment: Thanks for the time buddy. Yes this gives the correct answer.

Comment: Of all the variations on that page, what an odd one to choose, at least based on the performance metrics.

Comment: Fair enough. I basically chose one at random just to illustrate a correct way to call the table valued function.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - thanks but which out of those would you prefer ? The XML one ?

Comment: @VVV Honestly I'd prefer to [not split strings in the first place](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-now-with-less-t-sql). Is there a reason the database is seeing `a|delimited|string` instead of three distinct values?

Comment: @VVV And is there a reason you don't know what order they'll be in? e.g. why can't you just take a substring based on the first occurrence of `|`?